# Drupal: Search custom content type for mobile app

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-search

I need to search content (nodes) in drupal. The content type is custom, with many fields, like location, url, email, address and a few others. I tried writing my own queries, but the results were not satisfactory. I also tried using "node_search_execute" but it does not work out for multiple keywords and like if have an item with title "Books" node_search_execute wont work for "book".

Is there a good module that I can use to get results from my web service inside drupal or I should try with my queries to make it work.

NOTE: I need the results to be returned to a mobile app.

Can anyone guide me to do the thing right !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a new table of type MyIsam. Do not change the existing table type as it can destroy the relations.

Now either add the data to table while adding/editing or use a cron service to update this table. Perform full text search on this to get results.

OR

Use multiple queries to fetch data and then return the search results. (This approach may not be efficient but will work).